# How much data in MB can be sent/received from Windows phone 7+ to other WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to know the size of data (in MB) that i can send/receive from/by Windows phone 7/7.5 to any other device(phone or pc) at socket level using TCP or UDP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer ,if anybody interested can see here

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/dcf6e937-4e6a-4311-bfad-9f3b6abdd18d

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no limit in the data you can send/receive using sockets.

Comment: But as i know all other devices(mobile) have some limit on transfer, but unable to find for windows phone.